# froalaEditor.image.uploaded and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, froala

I'm trying to use the custom upload functionality for images in froala so have setup the following:

```
imagePaste: true,
    imageUploadParam: 'file',
    imageUploadParams: {
        froala: true,
    },
    imageUploadURL: '/update/files',
    imageUploadMethod: 'POST',
```

This successfully uploads the image to our server when an image is pasted in.

We need to rewrite the reponse we get from the server to build the url so have the following:

```
  'froalaEditor.image.uploaded' : (e, editor, response) => {
    var imageData = null;
    response = JSON.parse(response);

    fetch(
  "?partial=editorimage.json&type="+response[0].documentId,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }
).then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    imageData = json.authenticatedId;
    editor.image.insert(imageData, true, {'remedyTag': 'yes'}, editor.image.get(), {link:imageData});
  }
}));
```

}

The image is posted ok into the editor for the user to see and if I inspect the element it has my re-written URL so all good.

```
    <img class="fr-dib fr-error fr-draggable"
 src="http://server:8080/2018/02/06/807d2a29-a9df-4d38-ad44-b6970d82462e?expiration=1517925153113&amp;key=6IAFCT0&amp;signature=89-sDmKsYMW3Ylktft5mUu6YwnY=" 
style="width: 300px;" data-remedytag="yes">
```

The problem is that our redux state only has a 
 tag for the inserted image:

```
update(pin): null
editorState(pin): "<p><br></p>"
```

I have a saga attached to the onModelChange item in the FroalaEditor definiton which is firing fine for text.

If I manpulate the image (e.g. add a caption) then the state in redux then has the

```
update(pin): null
editorState(pin): "<p><span class="fr-img-caption fr-dib fr-error" style="width: 300px;"><span class="fr-img-wrap" style="width: 300px;"><img src="http://server:8080/2018/02/06/807d2a29-a9df-4d38-ad44-b6970d82462e?expiration=1517925153113&key=6IAFCT0&signature=89-sDmKsYMW3Ylktft5mUu6YwnY=" data-remedytag="yes"><span class="fr-inner">123<br><br></span></span></span></p>"
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was our server wasn't responding with {"link":"path/to/image"} I was hoping we could take the response and rework in the uploaded event, but it needs to be done before then - we're going to do that server side